# How do I convert JSON dictionary to XML?

Tags: json, xml, dictionary

Plenty of resources online for JSON to XML but only when they're in normal array format, not dictionary.

Does anyone know what I should do? I want to use XML in my project but when I convert it I just get the following which is of little use:

<0 KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j="[object Object]" KiQPi-1EiURvD3zK2IY="[object Object]"

what should I do?

Example of the JSON dictionary is below:

```
[{
  "-KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j": {
    "category": "1",
    "id": "-KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j",
    "image_url": "",
    "message": "Water leaking out side of it for ages now but it's coming out the bottom now too!",
    "postcode": "LL53",
    "reports": "0",
    "status": "0",
    "time": "21-04-2017 13:18:25",
    "title": "Leaking Bath, L12 area!",
    "user_id": "esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2"
  },
  "-KiQPi-1EiURvD3zK2IY": {
    "category": "3",
    "id": "-KiQPi-1EiURvD3zK2IY",
    "image_url": "/v0/b/fixee-164914.appspot.com/o/esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2514653921592.jpg",
    "message": "How much would it cost a week to keep this in decent shape? Had extortionate quotes and need it done cheap soon!",
    "postcode": "LE11 3UQ",
    "reports": "0",
    "status": "0",
    "time": "23-04-2017 16:25:23",
    "title": "Gardener Required!!",
    "user_id": "esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

for xml a root node is needed, where is the root node in your json?
try to work from xml to json using a converter like : http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/
that way you know how the xml must be formatted to get the json to be valid.

so for your example I first created xml, and then converted it to json:

```
<root>
   <KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j>
    <category>1</category>
    <id>-KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j</id>
    <image_url></image_url>
    <message>Water leaking out side of it for ages now but it's coming out the bottom now too!</message>
    <postcode>LL53</postcode>
    <reports>0</reports>
    <status>0</status>
    <time>21-04-2017 13:18:25</time>
    <title>Leaking Bath, L12 area!</title>
    <user_id>esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2</user_id>
</KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j>
<KiQPi-1EiURvD3zK2IY>
    <category>1</category>
    <id>-KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j</id>
    <image_url></image_url>
    <message>Water leaking out side of it for ages now but it's coming out the bottom now too!</message>
    <postcode>LL53</postcode>
    <reports>0</reports>
    <status>0</status>
    <time>21-04-2017 13:18:25</time>
    <title>Leaking Bath, L12 area!</title>
    <user_id>esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2</user_id>
</KiQPi-1EiURvD3zK2IY>

</root>
```

leads to:

```
{
  "root": {
    "KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j": {
      "category": "1",
      "id": "-KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j",
      "message": "Water leaking out side of it for ages now but it's coming out the bottom now too!",
      "postcode": "LL53",
      "reports": "0",
      "status": "0",
      "time": "21-04-2017 13:18:25",
      "title": "Leaking Bath, L12 area!",
      "user_id": "esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2"
    },
    "KiQPi-1EiURvD3zK2IY": {
      "category": "1",
      "id": "-KiFRirIKU_I0FIXWj1j",
      "message": "Water leaking out side of it for ages now but it's coming out the bottom now too!",
      "postcode": "LL53",
      "reports": "0",
      "status": "0",
      "time": "21-04-2017 13:18:25",
      "title": "Leaking Bath, L12 area!",
      "user_id": "esO8EE8aoLM3bvKalHNvI9Hv7Ra2"
    }
  }
}
```